# VueJS automation - Test Cafe vs. Nightwatch - Pros/Cons

Tags: testing, vue.js, vuejs2, nightwatch.js, testcafe

I am looking at creating automation test cases for a VueJS application that will be supported across several different desktop browsers and mobile (iOS and Android) browsers.  I have came across several options including Protractor, Test Cafe, Nightwatch, and Cypress.  Cypress is only supported with Chrome browsers so I won't be able to use that, and Protractor seems more geared towards testing of Angular applications.  So I am looking for feedback from people who have used Test Cafe or Nightwatch.

**Questions**:

1. Which of the 2 tools do you find better and why?
2. What are the pros/cons of one vs. the other? (Selenium Based vs. Not doesn't matter to me)
3. Does either support mobile browser testing?
4. Did anyone have any issues with either that stopped you from using it and going with another approach?

Comment: I haven't used test cafe at all so I can't speak to that. However, I have used Protractor, Nightwatch and WebdriverIO. Of the three I actually prefer WebdriverIO. Like you said, Protractor is more geared towards angular apps. It can be used with non angular apps but it's kind of a pain. I've been using nightwatch at my current job for the last three months and I'm not really a fan of the syntax. I prefer webdriverio because as a tester who also writes code it feels more natural to me. I write all my tests in typescript using classes, interfaces, enums, etc.

Comment: It also has mobile support which is something you need. Check it out http://webdriver.io/

Comment: I'll check that out, thank you!

Comment: There is an article that compares TestCafe and Nightwatch: https://60devs.com/functional-testing-of-web-applications-using-testcafe-and-nightwatch.html
Additionally you can find what the main differences between TestCafe and Selenium-based solutions in this post: https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/why-not-use-selenium/47

Comment: (1) "Which is better", (2) what are pros/cons and (4) "have you had issues?" are clearly opinion-based questions. I therefore flagged this question entry as such.

Answer (score 4):

I have not used test cafe till now but I have used Nightwatch. It's really a nice framework developed in nodeJS.

**Pros:**

1. List item
2. Built-in test runner- Built-in command line test runner which can run the tests in parallel.
3. Parallel cross-browser testing- Same test we can run in multiple browsers at the same time
4. Much better api then selenium webdriver
5. Inbuilt assertion library
6. Inbuilt screenshots
7. Return object- Every method that you call will return an object. We can have a chain of command like open.click.sendkeys.wait.click.select.end
8. Syntax- looks the easiest and the most readable
9. It has a very good inbuilt debugging mechanism.
10. It is extendable- You can write your own custom commands and add custom assertions
    10.Grouping tests- You can group test. eg Smoke test, login test etc
11. It is also supported across several different desktop browsers and mobile browsers (iOS and Android)

**Cons:** less support

Answer (score 1):

I had experiance with nightwatch js . Its very easy to implement.Its suport all languages like react js, angular js or any scripting language. Only the neagtive side is less support. Another better option is webdriver.io (not selenium webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

Nightwatch is based on selenium. Test Cafe has his own mechanism and have some advantages, like mobile testing and auto waiting mechanism and simpler setup.

Comment: This should be a comment.